# Release objects in List adapter Android

Tags: android, memory-management

I am using  a separate class as adapter for my list view that extends Base adapter.My question is how can I release the memory used by objects like arraylist in the adapter. Please help me.

Comment: its the job of gc to free memory. listview recycle's views. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#clear().  Remove all elements from the list.

Comment: I am trying to find out memory leaks in my application.As part of fix arraylist=null; is added in Activities onDestroy. But there is no OnDestroy for adapter so I don't know how to do that for adapter. there is no need to release the objects in adaper?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk. check this video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The garbage collector should take care of freeing memory you are no longer using.

OnDestroy is meant for Activities, it's not something you need to manually call. Rather, it's something that is automatically called when an Activity is about to be destroyed